# MS Access & VB.Net Connection String in Settings Using User Profile

Tags: vb.net

Hello I Have Made an Application with vb.net and ms access The Connection String in My.Settings is As Shown:

```
Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=C:\Users\Ammar\AppData\Local\Empolyee Attendance\Data.mdb;Jet OLEDB:Database Password=ammar87
```

So as I have to install this application in many computers, I have tried to make my connection string as shown:

```
Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=C:\Users\%UserProfile%\AppData\Local\Empolyee Attendance\Data.mdb;Jet OLEDB:Database Password=ammar87
```

But It Did not work so how can I make the userprofile location in my connection string so that It can varies from computer to an other computer

Best Regards.

Comment: How doesn't it work? What happens when you use this? What error you are getting?

Comment: I got cannot find %UserProfile%\AppData\Local\Empolyee Attendance\Data.mdb

Comment: An environment variable in a connection string will not be expanded automatically.  You have to expand the variable first and then use the result as your connection string.

Comment: Have you checked the path then? If the file is there. Then use this line.

`string path = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Documents);`

This will give you the initial path. Add remaining part of the string to create connection string.

Comment: Also, you should prefer to use `My.Computer.FileSystem.SpecialDirectories` or `Environment.GetFolderPath` to using environment variables if possible.

Comment: @jitendragarg, I think you used the wrong `SpecialFolder` value based on the path the OP wants.

Comment: I'm using Environment.GetFolderPath in code but how to set it in the settings

Comment: @NovaDesign, you don't set it in the settings.  You can't.  If your path needs to be evaluated at run time then you need to evaluate it at run time.  The only exception is when using "|DataDirectory|".

Comment: Sorry, wrong folder. You need `SpecialFolder.UserProfile`. And no, it can't be done from config using this method. Not sure, if there is a better option. But this is probably easiest. Keep the second part with password and all in config file. Then when you open the connection, add the two strings.

Comment: @NovaDesign, per the good advice you have already been given, build your connection in code instead of in config. [Use OleDbConnectionStringBuilder](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbconnectionstringbuilder(v=vs.110).aspx) to make it easy.